# Concatenate Two Tables in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

**EDIT** Evidently I did not read the Pig docs closely. The `UNION` operator is what I'm looking for (e.g. `C = UNION A, B;`).

Assume I have two tables in Pig, `A` and `B` that look as follows:

```
A=
(1)
(2)
(3)

B=
(4)
```

How do I generate and third table, `C` that concatenates tables `A` and `B`:

```
C=
(1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UNION` is a standard operator and would be in any basic introduction to Pig:

```
C = UNION A, B;
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that in the documentation. Thank you!